# All else being equal, do rules of good Spanish writing encourage symmetry in sentences?

Tags: voz-pasiva, escritura

Primero mi pregunta en español:

**Todo lo demás constante, ¿alientan las reglas de buena escritura en español la simetría en las frases?**

**Details in English:**

I recently came upon the following in the grammar book, [***Spanish Grammar in Context***](https://books.google.com/books?id=ULHpAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22spanish+grammar+in+context%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR29qE__nRAhXhjFQKHVBTBkUQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22spanish%20grammar%20in%20context%22&f=false):

> **El cambio climático se intensifica a medida que la contaminación recalienta el planeta.**

It is part of an exercise in which you are asked to rewrite sentences using a verb shown in brackets.  (For this particular sentence, the verb in brackets is "estar.")  The answer key gives two verb phrases as follows:

> **está intensificando
>
> está recalentando**

This led me to think about what makes for better Spanish writing.  For example, in English there is this notion of sentence symmetry where an effort is made to match certain elements that exist in one part of the sentence with similar elements in the clause that follows it.  To cut to the chase, I'm going to list variations of this sentence below in the hope that someone can tell me what nuances in meaning exist (if worth noting) and/or which you consider to be the best of these sentences.

> El cambio climático **se intensifica** a medida que la contaminación **recalienta** el planeta.  (this is the first one listed)
>
> El cambio climático **está intensificando** a medida que la contaminación **está recalentando** el planeta. (this is the sentence after applying lesson instructions)
>
> El cambio climático **se intensifica** a medida que la contaminación **se recalienta** el planeta. (a version of the sentence using the passive in the first part and passive in the clause that follows)

I could add more variations, but I think the three above are enough to open this up for discussion/answers.

I would imagine that if I had been an English major or English teacher, I might be able to answer this myself based off of the English translations since I suspect rules of good English writing are similar to those in Spanish.  Not having studied this, I'd be interested in knowing what you think.

As always, thanks in advance.

**Detalles en español:**

Recientemente encontré lo siguiente en el libro de gramática [***Spanish Grammar in Context***](https://books.google.com/books?id=ULHpAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22spanish+grammar+in+context%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR29qE__nRAhXhjFQKHVBTBkUQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22spanish%20grammar%20in%20context%22&f=false):

> **El cambio climático se intensifica a medida que la contaminación recalienta el planeta.**

Es parte de un ejercicio en que se pide reescribir frases utilizando un verbo indicado entre paréntesis cuadrados.  (Para esta frase, el verbo entre paréntesis es "estar.")  La clave de respuestas da los dos sintagmas verbales que siguen:

> **está intensificando
>
> está recalentando**

Esto me llevó a pensar en qué es lo que mejora la escritura / contribuye a una mejor escritura en español.  Por ejemplo, en inglés, existe una noción de simetría en frases, por la que se hace un esfuerzo por igualar ciertos elementos que existen en una parte de la frase en la cláusula que la sigue. Para ir al grano, voy a listar variaciones de esta frase abajo, con la esperanza de que alguien pueda decirme qué matices de significado existen (si vale la pena señalarlos) y/o cuál considera que sería la mejor de estas frases.

> El cambio climático **se intensifica** a medida que la contaminación **recalienta** el planeta.  (ésta es la primera listada)
>
> El cambio climático **está intensificando** a medida que la contaminación **está recalentando** el planeta. (ésta es la frase después de aplicar las instrucciones de la lección)
>
> El cambio climático **se intensifica** a medida que la contaminación **se recalienta** el planeta. (una versión de la frase que utiliza la pasiva en la primera parte y la pasiva en la cláusula que sigue)

Podría añadir más variaciones, pero creo que las tres de arriba / precedentes son suficientes para abrir este tema a debate y respuestas.

Imaginaría que si hubiera sido profesora de Lengua Inglesa, podría ser capaz de responder esta pregunta yo misma basándome en las traducciones al inglés, puesto que sospecho que las reglas de buena escritura son las mismas en inglés que en español.  No habiendo estudiado este tema, me interesaría conocer su opinión.

Como siempre, gracias de antemano.

Comment: It already is in parallel: both are in the active voice, just one happens to be a reflexive verb and the other a non reflexive. Sometimes it can be ambiguous whether a verb is reflexive or fake passive, but on the second part it's important to note the impossibility of fake passive without omitting the word *contaminación*

Comment: Las opciones primera y tercera son exactamente iguales.

Comment: @JMVanPelt Tiene razón.  Olvidé añadir "se" antes de "recalienta."  Desde entonces lo he añadido.  Gracias por mencionarlo.

Comment: For me the fact that the author is trying to express two things occurring in parallel makes it quite appealing to have the two phrases (or do I mean clauses) parallel as well so your second and third options have a good sound to me. I am not a native hispanophone though.

Comment: @guifa I find your comment very interesting.  It has peeled off yet one more layer of the onion of the Spanish language for me.  Since I still feel as if I have a lot more to learn about reflexive usage in Spanish and even more about this thing you call the "fake passive," it will take some time for me to digest what you have written, but thank you for alluding to concepts I had been unaware of before.  I look forward to learning more about them and if you have any resources to suggest, I would be most interested in learning of your recommendations.

Comment: I have a question for you, @guifa (or anyone who can answer this question).  You say that _one just happens to be a reflexive verb_ (which must refer to **se intensifica**).  Why does it have to be reflexive?  Why couldn't it be considered passive voice?  And, as a non-native speaker, is there any good way to be able to determine which is which?

Comment: If you ask a question about the different uses of "se", I'd be delighted to try and explain them as best as I can.

Comment: @Gustavson I'll see what may have already been previously asked/answered to see if I can come up with a good ? for you about it.  In the meantime, I serendipitously came upon a section about the **"false passive"** in the latest Spanish grammar book I'm reading -- [**_1001 Pitfalls in Spanish._**](http://barronseduc.com/0764143476.html)  It devotes an entire 54 words to the topic, so there's probably more to learn about it, but this is the first book in which I've seen this addressed (although I am sure there are many others).  Does anyone have any additional recommendations for further study?

Comment: I'd really like to know what they mean by "false" or "fake passive." There's actually nothing of the sort in real Spanish grammar. The *Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española" must devote large sections to "se", but perhaps not as well organized as some people might need to make clear which is which. I think you and others like you might need some contrastive analysis of the question (Spanish-English), and I'm sure I have some notes on that from my days as a student of translation.

Comment: @Gustavson Interesting that someone of your credentials was not familar with the fake/false passive.  I feel better now for not having learned of it earlier.  The thing is, it is understandable that it wouldn't be found in a grammar book for native Spanish speakers (which you appear to be) because it doesn't exist.  A "fake passive" is a phrase in English that appears to be passive but is actually (and I deviate from what I just read in _1001 Pitfalls_ a bit here) simply a nominal phrase/sentence.

Comment: For example, in English, "The door is closed," can mean that the door is closed by someone (in general, at some point in time, we just don't know who closes it).  However, it can also mean that the door is closed (wherein the door's condition or state of being is described … THE DOOR = CLOSED).  In Spanish, the first can be expressed by "se cierra" and the latter by "está cerrada."  Without additional contextual clues one cannot know whether it is truly passive in English, but I would venture to guess that nobody except maybe English or Linguistics grad students engage in the discussion of it.

Comment: @LisaBeck, I am aware of that phenomenon in English, but as you know in Spanish we have "ser + 'verbal' participle" for passive and "estar + 'adjectival' participle" for copulative constructions. There is then no such ambiguity in Spanish as there is in English. There are, however, a couple of ambiguities with "se" passives, as they may sometimes be interpreted as impersonal or as pronominal intransitives. "calentarse", for example, can be understood as "be heated" or as "become hot".

Comment: (I wouldn't call "calentarse" meaning "become hot" "reflexive", because it is not: the planet does not "heat itself"). I would perhaps speak about a "fake reflexive" (actually, in old grammar, there was the "cuasirreflejo"). A "se" passive is a passive proper in Spanish.

Comment: @Gustavson I'm going to have to get back to you on your offer of explaining the different uses of "se."  From threads within spanish.stackexhange and elsewhere, I've just poured a lot of new information into my existing cerebral structure about the uses of "se."  Some of it touches on my earlier question -- Why does "se intensifica" have to be reflexive? -- to the point that the question is somewhat ebbing away into some form of understanding albeit into the murkiness of which language sometimes is.  So, though I have no question for you now, there are sure to be other questions in the future.

Comment: @LisaBeck The answer to that is simple: "intensificarse" is intransitive, "intensificar" is transitive. No reflexive meaning whatsoever, at the most a "reflexive appearance". I was well aware of your confusion, that's why I offered my help.

Comment: Regarding the third suggested translation I made, there's a difference between "recalentar" and "recalentarse" according to this source [**here**](https://dictionary.reverso.net/spanish-english/recalentar).  I think both of these can be used in this sentence, but the meanings are slightly different.  This may or may not work with other verbs.  As a case in point, I don't think I could use "cambiarse" without drastically changing the meaning or creating a very awkward sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first sentence, with "se intensifica" and "recalienta," is of course fine. ("se recalienta," as guifa said in his comment, is not possible.)

However, it'd be perfect in Spanish to say:

- El cambio climático **se está intensificando** a medida que la contaminación **recalienta** el planeta.

"está recalentando" would not be possible because, combined with "a medida que," it would suggest with excessive emphasis an action at the precise moment of speaking, and with "la contaminación" as subject the result would be absurd. However, for some unfathomable reason, the progressive can work if we use a quasi-reflexive with "se":

- El cambio climático **se está intensificando** a medida que **se está recalentando** el planeta a causa de / como consecuencia de la contaminación.

I don't think replicating the same verb form in the two parts of the sentence will contribute to improving style, at least in the sentence you have provided.

Comment: Before reading your answer, I had thought that maybe this question was a bit too in the weeds or not specific enough to post, but after reading what you've added, I'm really glad I did post it.  I posted a comment earlier and am now revising it, because I've been thinking about your comment for a while now and something about it has kept rising up in my mind.  It concerns your statement _"está recalentando" would not be possible because, combined with "a medida que," it would suggest with excessive emphasis an action at the precise moment of speaking_.

Comment: After reading through it a couple more times, isn't that what the sentence is attempting to convey?  Perhaps my translation of the sentence will help others understand why I'm asking this question.  My translation of _El cambio climático está intensificando a medida que la contaminación está recalentando el planeta_ is: _Climate change is intensifying as pollution is warming the planet._

Comment: I used "as" for "a medida que," but I think other translations of "a medida que" could also be "to a measure that" or even "because."  So, is it not possible that emphasis, with respect to climate change intensifying and the planet warming, couldn’t be intended?  I was not previously aware that progressive usage was limited to the speaker’s time reference.  I understand that some concepts are very related to the viewpoint of the speaker (e.g., traer/llevar), but I have never heard of this.

Comment: Though I've had some more time to think about this and obviously may seem to be questioning something you've written, I still award you with the green checkmark.  If nothing else, it has made me aware that I should perhaps add an English translation to Spanish sentences I am enquiring about.  In that way, we all walk onto the same sheet of understanding.  At any rate, I think you are an incredibly gifted and informative contributor to this forum and look forward to more from you in the future.

Comment: @LisaBeck, thank you for your kind compliments (I wish I was worthy of them). "a medida que" is a very good translation equivalent for "as." Another is "al mismo tiempo que." We also have the rather infrequent and formal "según" and "conforme." I understand your confusion. To my native ear, "la contaminación está recalentado el planeta" sounds more active and therefore faster than "El cambio climático se está intensificando" (note the use of "se").

Comment: The progressive is not restricted to the time of speaking, but in my humble opinion that sentence with "a medida que" renders "la contaminación" an unsuitable subject for "recalentar el planeta" in the continuous form. There is something in the semantics of "recalentar" that causes some unbalance with "intensificarse" if the former takes an active subject. HPH :)

Answer (score 2):

Although the Grammatical rules in Spanish provide apmple headroom to compose the most capricious and contorted sentences while retaining the idea you wish to convey, providing for great creative possibilities, while trying to create symmetric constructs such as these, you run the risk of easily falling into pitfalls and vices of style such as cacophony.

While the symmetric sentences are correct, they do tend to abuse repetitive sounds of the infinitive forms, only made worse by being verbs with the same number of syllables! Thus the cacophony feels more noticeable (the pair *intensifica, recalienta* with *está intensificando, está recalentando*)

The whole paragraph may benefit from a few synonyms here and there, conveying the same meaning, yet avoiding the repetitive same length words, it all flows a lot better.

I'd switch *intensifica* for *acentúa* (3 syllables, 3 strong vowels vs 4 syllables and 1 strong vowel. in the former) and the whole thing flows a lot better, with no change in meaning.

Also, intensifica Is a *grave accented word* [1] which increments it's metrics by 1 virtual syllable, making it yet more markedly rythmic.

1: is grave accent for stress on the next-to-last syllable correct? Suddenly I'm doubtful that's the correct term

Answer (score 1):

La oración mejor redactada es:

> El cambio climático se intensifica a medida que la contaminación calienta el planeta.

The sentence: El cambio climático está intensificando (you need to add something here) a medida que la contaminación está recalentando (re warming? it is better to stick with calentando here) el planeta.

The sententce: El cambio climático se intensifica a medida que la contaminación se recalienta (you could just change se recalienta to calienta) el planeta.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few thoughts to share and will put them here even though they don't really constitute an answer.

1. What is better Spanish writing?  Well, before thinking about that, what is good Spanish writing?  There are tons of writers and readers in Spanish who are fond of verbiage that doesn't add much meaningful content, but that adds patina to the piece.  So, "good Spanish writing" is already a subjective thing.  Then, there's "better" Spanish writing.  Better than what, or whom?  I'd have an easier time thinking about your question if I understood better the point of view of the question.  Also, I didn't understand whether the proposed rewrites of the original sentence were suggested by you, or whether they were touted in the book.
2. Going from English to Spanish isn't like going from English to Chinese.  English and Spanish have so much in common that even though I didn't understand the question very well, it seems like a good bet that if you take a list of rhetorical devices used fairly often in English and try to find examples of them in Spanish writing, you'll probably have pretty good luck finding some.
3. Have you picked out a small handful of authors *you* really like, and tried to pull out specific examples of rhetorical devices, etc., from their writing, that you particularly liked?
4. What kind of writing are you doing/will you be doing, that you want to improve in?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really fully understand the concept of simmetry you are trying to apply here. It's a matter of the time of the verbs, the position of the different parts of the phrases, adjectives, nouns?

Anyway, I didn't know that written English had such a rule, but I really, really doubt that Spanish has it. In fact I'm pretty sure that Spanish doesn't have it and I was about to tell you just that, but I just contained myself, just in case.

See, you can say a huge lot of things in one phrase using Spanish, if you want an example one book come to my mind: "Las intermitencias de la muerte" from José Saramago. If you read that book, you'll read some of the largest phrases I've read in my whole live. It's just madness how this writer can handle such phrases with so many information in every one of them, and still being not only readable but pleasant and beautiful.

You can not make such phrases simmetric, and you shouldn't. Every part of the phrase have something to say and a specific way to say it to express what the writer wants to express.
Simmetry doesn't matter at all. What matters is the what and how you are trying to express, and you use all the tools you have to achieve it.
There's no more about it. Forget about simmetry unless you are writing poetry and you need it for the rhythm, or specific things like that.

**Edit:**

Given the comments of the user Gustavson, I want to clarify that the example of Saramago was only to illustrate the concept that simmetry shouldn't be a concern while writing, but simply an added thing both on purpose or randomly. The most improtant is what you are trying to express and how.

So, I've collected other example from the book "Fortunata y Jacinta" from Benito Pérez Galdós. It doesn't have the same large phrases, but it would be interesting that you read it and try to find that simmetry in the several phrases of the paragraph:

> Me explicaré mejor. Quiero decir que al maltratar a tu rival le has dado la victoria sobre ti. El hombre a quien queréis las dos pudo haber vacilado antes de elegir la que definitivamente había de merecer su amor. Ahora no vacilará. Entre una que se descompone y hace las brutalidades que tú hiciste y otra que padece y es maltratada, el amor tiene que preferir a la víctima. Toda víctima es por sí interesante. Todo verdugo es por sí odioso. En un pleito de amor, la víctima gana siempre. Ésta es una verdad que está escrita en el corazón humano como en un libro, y yo leo en él tan claro como leemos una noticia en *El Imparcial*. Yo lo sé todo; nada se me oculta. Demasiadas pruebas tienes de ello.

If you was referring to more formal writings, like essays, letters, I apologize, but honestly I thought it was more general and was an interesting question, so I had to give an interesting answer :)

Comment: José Saramago wrote in Portuguese, and no matter how good the translations of his books into Spanish may be, it'd be much better for Spanish language learners to read works originally written in Spanish. Also, Lisa is asking about more technical, not literary, writing -- perhaps essays, articles, or reports. (If you don't mind, I could edit your answer, which contains quite a few mistakes.)

Comment: Of course you can edit the answer, I'm a native spanish speaker and I'm aware that my English have a few mistakes ;) As always, correct the english but not the meaning.

Comment: Regarding Saramago, I know he wrote in Portuguese, it was simply an example that simmetry is not something one should worry about when writing, giving an extreme example that honestly, came to my mind almost immediately, given how was wrotten that book and the habit of Saramago of use puntuation the way he wanted. I think it was like a way of thinking of him and he was known precisely by it. But you are right that the better would be to give a proper Spanish book example, I think I have one in mind and I'll edit the question when I find it.

Comment: Regarding the literary vs technical, I didn't understand that. I just understood that the question was more about how to write properly in general. Did I misunderstood it?

Comment: This comment is in reply to the answer by Nox, specifically this: _I don't really fully understand the concept of simmetry (sic) you are trying to apply here._  For starters, my notion of symmetry in writing really stems mainly from some distant memory from my high school public education and reinforced by reading the book (_Handbook for Writers, 7th Edition_), which my mother used for her business college writing class.  The _Handbook for Writers_ refers to it as "parallelism."

Comment: An excerpt from _Handbook for Writers_: **_Parallel structure puts similar ideas into the same kinds of grammatical constructions.  If one idea is expressed by a phrase, other equal ideas should be expressed by phrases.  If one idea is expressed by an infinitive, a gerund, or a clause, other equal ideas should be expressed by duplicate grammatical constructions.  … [it makes] sentences grammatically clear by keeping elements of the same grammatical rank and function in the same kind of grammatical construction._**

Comment: The book goes on to provide numerous examples of why parallelism should be used, ranging from the simply awkward to the erroneous.  Here is an example of one of its sentence revisions: _Sam is tall, with blue eyes, and has a congenial manner._  REVISED: _Sam is tall, blue-eyed, and congenial._  That example strays a bit from the example I used for the main question of this discussion thread, but it is this notion/idea/concept that I refer to.

Comment: If this topic interests any of you who are reading this, and you can't get your hands on a copy of the book I've mentioned (recommended), or one like it, you may want to visit this web page here: http://writing2.richmond.edu/writing/wweb/parstruc.html.  To view the reviews 12 others have made of _Handbook for Writers_ at Amazon.com, click on this link here: [_**Handbook for Writers**_](https://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Writers-Charvat-Willia-Leggett/dp/B000Z2PYU4).  HTH.

Comment: The concept which @LisaBeck is discussing is known (as she says) as parallelism as a rhetorical device. See the Wikipedia entries https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paralelismo_(ret%C3%B3rica) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(rhetoric). The Spanish one has some examples from native writers and also a reference to its common use in translations from the Hebrew in the Bible.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question better now, having recently coached one of my children to take an English Writing exam where the practice exam focused heavily on how to correct sentences that didn't respect the parallel structure principle you described:

> Parallel structure puts similar ideas into the same kinds of grammatical constructions. If one idea is expressed by a phrase, other equal ideas should be expressed by phrases. If one idea is expressed by an infinitive, a gerund, or a clause, other equal ideas should be expressed by duplicate grammatical constructions. … [it makes] sentences grammatically clear by keeping elements of the same grammatical rank and function in the same kind of grammatical construction.

I think the easiest way to understand this topic is to look at an example of a sentence that has a *problem* -- because it doesn't respect parallel structure:

> (Bad!) For this recipe, you must first
>
> - prepare the marinade
> - let the chicken sit in the marinade for a couple of days
> - it's important to keep the chicken refrigerated during this time
> - discard the marinade before cooking

(I just made that up as an illustration -- don't try to follow that as though it were an actual recipe.)

The bullet that isn't consistent with the others, in its structure, is "it's important to keep the chicken refrigerated during this time," because all the other bullets have just the predicate -- no subject.  A solution to the problem might be:

> importantly, keep the chicken refrigerated during this time

Perhaps "consistency" would be a clearer term than "parallel structure."  But teaching materials in the US do use the term "parallel structure."

For the question, does Spanish also require this consistency or parallel structure in the same way, the answer is yes.

However, boring sentences are to be avoided in both languages.

Example of a boring sentence:

> I understand the question better now, because I recently coached one of my children to take an English Writing exam, and I helped him review the topic of *parallel structure.*

Less boxy:

> I understand the question better now, having recently coached one of my children to take an English Writing exam which focused heavily on the topic of *parallel structure*.